# How do I process (running any algorithms like BFS etc on) a large graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, system-design

I am trying to think of possible ways to solve such problem where there is a huge graph which can't fit into one machine. How would one run any algorithm like BFS or DFS on such graph.

Comment: It would fetch the data from disk when needed.

Comment: Do you mean it won't fit into memory, or that it won't even fit into storage?

Comment: Cache as many nodes as practical on the local machine. Fetch nodes from remote storage when needed. Dump the [least-recently-used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#LRU) node from cache to make room for the new node.  Or plan B: buy more memory.

Comment: @arekolek: Yes assuming my graph is of size peta bytes. which might not fit into single machine storage.

Comment: @user3386109  sounds interesting but how about the scenario when one fan out of BFS explores so much data which is not available on same host storage itself?  I do looked into few theoretical ideas like developing I/O model or cache oblivious data structure etc.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in distributed algorithms. A distributed version of an algorithm could be used to find a solution for it while using multiple computers. Distributed algorithms work basically so that every node in the graph runs it's own copy of the algorithm. The solution emerges by the nodes communicating with each other.